# Video backup solution in the Cloud

Tags: video, photos.app, dropbox, backup

I'm about to purchase the new Macbook Pro with Retina display and I want to get the cheapest version.  But it only comes with a 256gbyte hard drive.  I probably use 30gbytes for all my data and 500gbytes for home videos (growing fast too).

Can I easily attach a USB/thunderbolt external hard drive to store my videos through iPhoto when connecting my iPhone to my computer?  Is there a good solution to then back up that external hard drive on a cloud?  Dropbox and Google Drive are amazing backup solutions, but they cost so much money as I get closer to a terabyte and they don't seem to work with iPhoto so well.

Every 10 minute video from my iPhone takes up 2gbytes, this has to be a very common problem among parents...

Comment: What kind of upload speeds do you have so that you even consider regularly uploading lots of GB? ;)

Comment: @gentmatt - Upload speeds are not an issue.  I have plenty and I don't care if it takes a very long time either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in backing up the data, I can't recommend [BackBlaze](http://www.backblaze.com) highly enough. I'd tried Carbonite and Mozy with many little niggling issues and some larger flaws after several months use. I've been using BackBlaze for more than 2 years now and have restored data on several occasions, and migrated to 2 new systems with no problems. It's $5 per month for unlimited backup space.

Worth pointing out though that you don't access it as a share or folder as you would with something like Dropbox or Google Drive. It's a client app which just manages backups.

I use this in conjunction with Dropbox for all of my personal documents (I have 12gb from referrals now so that's enough for me) and Time Machine at home.

Comment: Backblaze looks great, can I easily store my iPhoto videos on an external hardrive and then restore on a new computer with iPhoto?

Comment: You just select which drives and folders you want to include/exclude. You can restore everything or selectively. Probably easier to take a look at it as part of the free trial, but from what you've said here, it seems to suit your requirements.

Comment: I just received an external USB 3.0 drive and am going to try BackBlaze when I set this up in the next day or 2.  This may be the best option, thanks.

Comment: External USB drive with BackBlaze seems to solve my problems, thanks AlanJC

Comment: Excellent to hear. I can't fault it, best solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's awkward to have iPhoto libraries on both internal and external disks. Aperture might be a better solution or you might want to just manage your videos outside of iPhoto instead.

Crashplan has some inexpensive unlimited backup plans available. It also can do additional backups to another local machine or locally attached hard disk.

My personal practice is to have a local backup and a remote backup using two different technologies so I use Time Machine locally to a Mac Mini that's my home server (although a Time Capsule or local hard disk would work just as well) and Crashplan for remote backups. Having a local backup is much more convenient so the remote is strictly for major disasters.

Comment: I ONLY need to store iPhoto videos externally.  I'm happy for iPhoto to have 0 videos on a local drive.